# How to fix FINISHME: Illegal color on vkCreateFramebuffer

Tags: java, lwjgl, vulkan

I am following the c vulkan tutorial and translating as I go but I am getting a error when creating the framebuffer.

../src/amd/vulkan/radv_device.c:4321: FINISHME: Illegal color

Does anyone know what this error means?

Ive tried to see if I forgot to input the swapchain format or colorspace in the creating of the graphics pipeline but no luck so far.

```
private static void createFrameBuffers() {
    swapChainFrameBuffers = new long[swapChainImageViews.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < swapChainFrameBuffers.length; i++) {
        LongBuffer attach = MemoryUtil.memCallocLong(1);
        attach.put(swapChainImageViews[i]);
        attach.flip();

            VkFramebufferCreateInfo framebuffInfo = VkFramebufferCreateInfo.create();
            framebuffInfo.sType(VkFramebufferCreateInfo.STYPE).renderPass(renderPass).pAttachments(attach)
                    .width(swapChainExtent.width()).height(swapChainExtent.height()).layers(1);

            LongBuffer p = MemoryUtil.memCallocLong(1);
            if (VK10.vkCreateFramebuffer(device, framebuffInfo, null, p) != VK10.VK_SUCCESS) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create framebuffer!");
            }
            swapChainFrameBuffers[i] = p.get(0);
            MemoryUtil.memFree(attach);
            MemoryUtil.memFree(p);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Having a look at the [source](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/bnieuwenhuizen/mesa/blob/2c7b4210f22df3afee14daff56e77673cf4fb40e/src/amd/vulkan/radv_device.c) and digging around a bit it seems that you get this message if the format is not "plain" (the comments say a plain format has width=height=1 so that might be the problem) or the type is ~0u (which could happen due to incompatible or unsupported channel settings, see here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/bnieuwenhuizen/mesa/blob/2c7b4210f22df3afee14daff56e77673cf4fb40e/src/amd/vulkan/radv_formats.c)

Comment: thx man! You helped me get to the solution!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

When creating the swap chain I was using and invalid surface format int. My mistake, came from my format support querying.